# Demuxing with FFmpeg - Unspecified pixel format

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, webassembly

I'm trying to use FFmpeg in the browser (compiled with Emscripten) to demux a video container. FFmpeg was built with all libraries for testing purposes.

Unfortunately, I get an error message that I don't know how to handle. I am trying to demux a file with an audio and video stream. When I do this, I get a warning during the avformat_find_stream_info method that reads:

```
- Stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
- Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), **none**, 1280x720, 2322 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
- Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
```

Furthermore, when I then start reading the frame, I get the error:

```
- "Invalid data found when processing input"
```

Here is the code I use (I will use pseudocode for better understanding).

```
formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
avioContext = avio_alloc_context(av_malloc(500_000), 500_000, 0, null, readFunction, null, null)

avioContext-\>seekable = 0;
avioContext-\>write_flag = 0;
formatContext-\>flags = AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO | AVFM_FLAG_FAST_SEEK;

formatContext-\>pb = avioContext.get();
formatContext-\>probesize = 10_000_000;
formatContext=analyzeduration = 10_000_000;

if(avformat_open_input(pformatContext, null, null, null) \< 0) {
return;
}

if(avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, null) \< 0) {
return;
}

audioStreamIndex = av_find_best_stream(formatContext, 1, -1, -1, null, 0);
videoStreamIndex = av_find_best_stream(formatContext, 0, -1, -1, null, 0);

while(chunksLeft) {
pPacket = av_packet_alloc()
av_read_frame(formatContext, pPacket);
}
```

I have already tried to increase the analyzeduration and the probesize. Unfortunately nothing works. But when I split the video and audio streams into separate files and try to demux them, I don't get any error message. So it only occurs when I have an audio and video stream in one container. I have tried with different files and always get the same error.